# Failover web Application server windows

Tags: failover

I want to set up a failover server for my web application server in windows. I found a method in Linux which uses HAproxy and Keepalived, but I could not find their alternative in windows. Is it possible with Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it does work in your network, NLB (network load balancer) could be, what you are searching for. If you need L7 load balancing, then you can combine NLB with ARR as recommended by Microsoft.
See: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-%28arr%29/achieving-high-availability-and-scalability-arr-and-nlb

Maybe MyWindowsHeartbeat is useful for building a custom solution, too: http://mywindowsheartbeat.codeplex.com/